# Remove uploaded files before the 6 hours cron?

Tags: 8, files

I have a custom Content Entity in wich definition there is a 'file' field.
The file widget works fine.
The 'Browse' button allows to select a file and uploads it to the proper server directory and the 'file_managed' and 'file_usage' tables are updated accordingly.
If I delete the entity, 'file_usage' record is deleted and in 'file_managed' table, the record has its status field set to '0'.
What I understood is that cron job removes all files in the directory with status = '0' after 6 hours.
My question is: how to have the file removed just after the submission of the delete form?

Comment: You can lower the time value in the admin configuration. I believe 1 hour is the lowest value.

Comment: The lowest value is currently 6 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`file_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_cron/8.4.x) contains the code that delete managed files. To adapt it to delete those files with their status set to 0, this is what I would use.

```
$file_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('file');
$fids = Drupal::entityQuery('file')->condition('status', 0)->execute();
$files = $file_storage->loadMultiple($fids);

foreach ($files as $file) {
  $references = \Drupal::service('file.usage')->listUsage($file);
  if (empty($references) && file_exists($file->getFileUri())) {
    $file->delete();
  }
}
```

This code returns you all the files matching those conditions. You can also use the following code to get them in batches of 100 per time.

```
$file_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('file');
$fids = Drupal::entityQuery('file')->condition('status', 0)->range(0, 100)->execute();
$files = $file_storage->loadMultiple($fids);

foreach ($files as $file) {
  $references = \Drupal::service('file.usage')->listUsage($file);
  if (empty($references) && file_exists($file->getFileUri())) {
    $file->delete();
  }
}
```

I didn't check, but it is probable you can also filter the returned file entities by the bundle using them.

Comment: I understand. But as I know that the file I want to remove can't be used elsewhere, wouldn't it be simpler to use directly `$file->delete()`?

Comment: It's better to check the files aren't really used.

Comment: OK then. Where do you think is the best place to put your code in my module?

Comment: I would say in the submission handler of the delete form, or in a submission handler of the delete form, if that form is not created from your module.